# Turning Off Direct Update MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a requirement to turn off direct update for an android app.

I uncomment this line :

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
    <testAppAuthenticity/> 
    <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
    <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
    <testDirectUpdate mode="perSession" />
</mobileSecurityTest>
```

and change `<testDirectUpdate mode="perSession" />` with `<testDirectUpdate mode="disabled" />` in `authenticationConfig.xml`.

Then i add `securityTest="mobileTests"` on `application-descriptor.xml`. So it looked like this :

```
<android version="1.2" securityTest="mobileTests">
    ...
</android>
```

The direct update stopped, but then an alert pops up saying :

> An error was encountered while processing the requested from the application.

That error happened every time the app tries to access backend server in the adapter.

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: That error relates to authenticity and not to direct update. Make sure your authenticity settings are in order.

Comment: @IdanAdar i'm sorry for the late reply. Would you kindly tell me where to check the authenticity? is it still in authenticationConfig.xml?

Comment: Look in your mobile security test. It says "testAuthenticity"...

Comment: @IdanAdar do mean `<testAppAuthenticity/> ` in authenticationConfig.xml? If so, what should i do with it? Sorry for the stupid questions, i'm still a newbie here

Comment: Do you need it there? Do you need to use authenticity? if not, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the inclusion of the `<appAuthenticity>` test. You cannot add this test w/out first properly configuring your application to use Application Authenticity Protection.

You can learn more about this here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

If you do not require authenticity, simply remove that line from the security test in authenticationConfig.xml.